# In a Categorical Variable (17 unique dummy variables), I want to select 10 unique variables which has highest frequency

Tags: r

I have a categorical variable name city which has 17 different cities' names. The total number of rows in the data is 228. I want to select only 10 cities that have the highest frequency in the data.

Comment: Hello Pawan, please share some data example so an answer can be delivered base on it.

Comment: if `city` is your variable, you can obtain the list of frequencies by `table(city)` and the ten most frequent names by `names(sort(table(city), dec=T))[1:10]`

Comment: Hello Ric, this worked, thank you, just one more thing, if I want the value count also of the the top 10, means if NewYork is repeated 20 times, and it is in top 10 then can I get Newyork with 20.

Comment: `as.data.frame(sort(table(city), dec=T)[1:10])`

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much, as a beginner, I spent 3 to 4 hours searching and trying different things from google.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, with reproducible data:

```
#Load in library:

library(dplyr)

#Use storms, a data set that comes with dplyr:

our_data <- storms

#Select the column that you want to judge the frequency of each value of:

our_data_column_of_interest <- our_data %>% dplyr::select(name)

#Make a data frame that is the top 10 most common occurences in that colun:

top_10 <- as.data.frame(table(our_data_column_of_interest)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Freq)) %>%  
  slice(1:10) %>% 
  dplyr::select(name) %>% 
  as_tibble()

#This makes a table out of our column, which summarizes the data by occurence, #arranges it by descending frequency, selects the first 10 rows, and then selects #just the information of interest, and makes it back into a tibble. 

#Now, filter for values in our original dataset based on the top 10 values that we created:


final_data <- our_data %>% filter(our_data$name %in% top_10$name)
```